# FR4 measurement tolerances

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I am going to get a PCB produced, but was wondering how the FR4 thickness measurements work, i.e. how thick are 1.6 and 0.8 FR4, in millimeters, to a few decimal places?

Comment: Aren't 1.6 and .8 thicknesses in mm excluding copper? and typically with a tolerance of something like 10%?

Comment: Ask your supplier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the specifications from your supplier, you will see something like this:

> STANDARD BOARD THICKNESS & TOL.       From 0.10 mm (0.004") to 3.50 mm
>   (0.138") Tolerance : IPC Class B

The "Class B" refers to the laminate thickness (no cladding), and you can refer to the [IPC information](http://www.ipc.org/4.0_knowledge/4.1_standards/ipc-2222-errata.pdf) for the relevant numbers[image]

To get the overall tolerance for a multilayer board you have to add up all the tolerances of each layer and the copper thickness tolerances.